# command line mail: setting the envelope from address

Tags: email

I configured the local postfix to use a relay (my own server).

All my emails are sent with the following from (username@machinename):

```
corti@MBP-von-Matteo.localdomain
```

This causes a reject from the majority of mail filters as the machine name does not have an entry in DNS.

Using sendmail I am able to set the envelope from:

```
sendmail -f matteo@corti.li to@example.com
```

Is there a way with `mail`? Is there a setting in `.mailrc` that I could use to specify the sender address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on *which* `mail` implementation you are using. For example, s-nail (aka Heirloom-mailx) accepts the `set sendmail-arguments="..."` option in mailrc, but it seems that bsd-mailx does not, neither does GNU mailutils.

However, I think you're trying to solve the problem at the wrong layer. The `mail` app doesn't interact with SMTP, so it shouldn't be worrying about SMTP envelope in the first place.

Instead, use [Postfix's](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#masquerade) `masquerade_domains` to rewrite the Envelope-From centrally.

Comment: I am using the standard macOS mail command. I could change the postfix settings, but this would be for all the users. And also setting the domain in postfix, the username would still be wrong (not so bad).

Comment: Isn't the relay host also the same for all users (and therefore handles the same domains)? I'm not familiar with macOS but I would suspect it has the BSD mailx variant.

Comment: You are right, the relay is anyway the same for all the users ....

Comment: Regarding username mismatches, as the envelope-from username is mostly just for delivery status notifications, it could probably be dealt with by aliasing corti@ to matteo@ in your inbound mail server (/etc/aliases) so that you could receive mail on both. The rest – spam checks, dkim/spf, etc – should only care about the domain.

Comment: Yes I could map it for non-deliveries.